# Resizing images and displaying side by side with justification

Tags: html, css

I have created an HTML template, to which I will push data from SQL using python and print it as pdf. The document needs to be printed always in landscape. I have achieved the functionality, but the logo on the right gets offset by an awkward amount and looks odd.

Please find the image as below:
[image: distance between heading and logos to both sides are unequal]

However, if I don't resize the image, the spaces are somewhat even but the image is too big, as below:
[image]

My code is as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: powderblue;
        }
        @media print {
            @page {
                size: landscape;
            }
        }/*required because this page will always have to be printed in landscape */
        .Row{
            display: flex;
        }
        .Cell{
            align-items: center;
        }
        .Cell h1{
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .Cell h2{
            text-align: center;
        }
        .Cell .logo{
            width: 30%;
            height: auto;
        }    
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell">
            <img src="logo1.jpg" alt="logo1" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
            <h1>THIS IS A VERY LONG MAIN HEADING XXX</h1>
            <h2>THIS IS A SUBHEADING</h2>
            <br>
            <h2>ANOTHER SUB HEADING</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
            <img src="logo2.jpg" alt="logo2" class="logo">
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone could point out to me how to make the logo equidistant from the headings, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have reconstructed your code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        body {
                    
            background-color: powderblue;
        }
        @media print {
            @page {
                size: landscape;
            }
        }/*required because this page will always have to be printed in landscape */
        .Row{
            display: flex;
                        flex-direction: row;
                        /* align-items: center; */
                        justify-content: center
        }
        .Cell{
                        /* justify-content: center */
                        align-items: center;
            text-align:center;

        }
        .Cell .logo{
            width: 30%;
            height: auto;
        }    
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/173/200/200.jpg?hmac=avUVgEVHNuQ4yZJQhCWlX3wpnR7d_fGOKvwZcDMLM0I" alt="logo1" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
            <h1>THIS IS A VERY LONG MAIN HEADING XXX</h1>
            <h2>THIS IS A SUBHEADING</h2>
            <br>
            <h2>ANOTHER SUB HEADING</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
           <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/173/200/200.jpg?hmac=avUVgEVHNuQ4yZJQhCWlX3wpnR7d_fGOKvwZcDMLM0I" alt="logo2" class="logo">
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

This below link will guide you much better way:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

---

Setting the width of `<img>` elements to percentage value is a little confusing because their containers don't have a specified width, so it isn't clear what the width should be.

I assume you wanted the first and last `.Cell` to be `30%` wide, but logos smaller and pushed to the opposite ends of the page. I set the width of the logos to be `100px`, but you can tweak that as you like. The key part is pushing the logo in the last `.Cell` to the right, one way to do it using Flexbox:

```
.Cell:last-child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

The `align-items` declaration is there so that the logo doesn't stretch to take up the height of the container.

I also removed some of the the `align-items` declarations from your code that weren't doing anything because they weren't Flex containers.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        body { 
            background-color: powderblue;
        }
        @media print {
            @page {
                size: landscape;
            }
        }
        .Row {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center
        }

        .Cell h1{
            text-align: center;
        }
        .Cell h2{
            text-align: center;
        }

        .Cell:first-child,
        .Cell:last-child {
            width: 30%;
        }

        .Cell:last-child {
            display: flex;
            align-items: flex-start;
            justify-content: flex-end;
        }

        .Cell img {
            width: 100px;
            height: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/173/200/200.jpg?hmac=avUVgEVHNuQ4yZJQhCWlX3wpnR7d_fGOKvwZcDMLM0I" alt="logo1" class="logo">
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
            <h1>THIS IS A VERY LONG MAIN HEADING XXX</h1>
            <h2>THIS IS A SUBHEADING</h2>
            <br>
            <h2>ANOTHER SUB HEADING</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
           <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/173/200/200.jpg?hmac=avUVgEVHNuQ4yZJQhCWlX3wpnR7d_fGOKvwZcDMLM0I" alt="logo2" class="logo">
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```